# Django filter by model method, kind of

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

It makes sense that querysets can't be filtered by model methods, querysets can only be filtered on the database and the database has no idea about the model method.

That being said, there's got to be a good way to do something similar right?

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    "An individual discussion post in the forum"
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)

    def last_reply(self):
        "latest reply for a forum topic"
        if self.replies.all():
            return self.replies.latest('created')

        return None


class TopicReply(models.Model):
    "A reply to a discussion topic or to another reply"
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name="replies")
    content = models.CharField(max_length="1000")
    parent_reply = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies')
```

Here are my two models, what I want to do is order topics by it's last reply date. With the queryset I've tried sorting in memory with `return sorted(queryset, key=lambda t:t.last_reply())` but there are null values and it errors in Python 3. Instead of returning None in the `last_reply` method, I've tried returning an empty string or `TopicReply.objects.none()` but the sorted function doesn't like any of those.

Comment: which version of Django are you on?

Comment: I'll have a think, have deleted my answer since it was wrong. to do it on the python side you could just have a more elaborate key function in `sorted` to  provide numeric values to sort on